# sending QTreeWidgetItem to a function with python

Tags: python, contextmenu, pyqt4, qtreewidget

I'm trying to make a program using Python, Komodo and QT4.

I'm trying to send a QTreeWidgetItem to a function after it was selected by the user with the mouse. All I was able to do is to move the position of the X and Y of the selected point by the mouse. Can anybody tell me how to send an QTreeWidgetItem to a function?

This is my code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.treeWidget = QtGui.QTreeWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.treeWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(155, 50, 481, 361))
        self.treeWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("treeWidget"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 25))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.create_popup_menu()
        self.treeWidget.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.treeWidget.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.on_context_menu)
        string="default,default:cluster1,default:cluster1:clusterA,default:cluster2,default:cluster2:clusterA"
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.buildingTree(string)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Assignment1", None))
        __sortingEnabled = self.treeWidget.isSortingEnabled()

    def buildingTree(self, string):
        arrTree = []
        arrPath = []
        arrString = []
        arrString = string.split(",")
        root = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
        root.setText(0,arrString[0])
        arrTree.append(root)
        arrString.pop(0)
        for path in arrString:
            arrPath = path.split(":")
            nameOfFather = arrPath[len(arrPath)-2]
            arrTree.reverse()
            for node in arrTree:
                nameOfNode = node.text(0)
                if nameOfNode == nameOfFather:
                    sonNode = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(node)
                    sonNode.setText(0,arrPath[len(arrPath)-1])
                    arrTree.insert(0,sonNode)
                    arrTree.reverse()
                    break
        self.treeWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)        

    def new_cluster(self):
        print "New Cluster"

    def rename_cluster(self):
        print "Rename cluster"

    def delete_cluster(self):
        print "Delete cluster"

    def create_popup_menu(self, parent=None):
        self.popup_menu = QtGui.QMenu(parent)
        self.popup_menu.addAction("New", self.new_cluster)
        self.popup_menu.addAction("Rename", self.rename_cluster)
        self.popup_menu.addSeparator()
        self.popup_menu.addAction("Delete", self.delete_cluster)

    def on_context_menu(self, pos):
        print "open menu"
        position = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
        print position
        position = pos
        print position
        print "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"
        """
        node = self.treeWidget.itemAt(position)
        print node
        node = self.treeWidget.setCurrentItem(node)
        print node.text(0)
        self.popup_menu.exec_(self.treeWidget.mapToGlobal(pos))

        global_pos = self.mapToGlobal(pos)
        t = self.itemAt(pos)
        self.setCurrentItem(t)
        """

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Shorten your code to the important part only. Nobody is going to read all that. Reading the description, your problem is likely to be about passing values to a callback (you need something like a `lambda` or `partial`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very unclear, because you are editing the file generated by `pyuic`, rather than importing it into your main application.

I have re-structured your code, and used an [event filter](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter) to handle the context-menu, which helps simplify the code a little. I have also used `lambda` functions to handle the menu actions. The code below assumes the file from `pyuic` is saved as `mainwindow_ui.py` (which you will obviously need to re-generate).

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from mainwindow_ui import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.buildingTree(
            "default,default:cluster1,default:cluster1:clusterA,"
            "default:cluster2,default:cluster2:clusterA"
            )
        self.treeWidget.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, target, event):
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.ContextMenu and
            target is self.treeWidget.viewport()):
            item = self.treeWidget.itemAt(event.pos())
            if item is not None:
                menu = QtGui.QMenu()
                menu.addAction(
                    "New", lambda: self.new_cluster(item))
                menu.addAction(
                    "Rename", lambda: self.rename_cluster(item))
                menu.addSeparator()
                menu.addAction(
                    "Delete", lambda: self.delete_cluster(item))
                menu.exec_(event.globalPos())
            return True
        return super(MainWindow, self).eventFilter(target, event)

    def new_cluster(self, item):
        print "New Cluster", item.text(0)

    def rename_cluster(self, item):
        print "Rename cluster", item.text(0)

    def delete_cluster(self, item):
        print "Delete cluster", item.text(0)

    def buildingTree(self, string):
        arrTree = []
        arrPath = []
        arrString = []
        arrString = string.split(",")
        root = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
        root.setText(0,arrString[0])
        arrTree.append(root)
        arrString.pop(0)
        for path in arrString:
            arrPath = path.split(":")
            nameOfFather = arrPath[len(arrPath)-2]
            arrTree.reverse()
            for node in arrTree:
                nameOfNode = node.text(0)
                if nameOfNode == nameOfFather:
                    sonNode = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(node)
                    sonNode.setText(0,arrPath[len(arrPath)-1])
                    arrTree.insert(0,sonNode)
                    arrTree.reverse()
                    break
        self.treeWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```